# Add two names (.format) to matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, title

I'm trying to add a title to my graphs with two formats using two loops but the result desired is not showing up with Matplotlib in Python. The goal is two graphs with titles like this:

1st graph: "Graph 1: Dots"

2nd graph: "Graph 2: Lines"

This is the code I have been trying:

```
types = ['Dots','Lines']

for graph in range(2):
    ax  = fig.add_subplot(1,2,graph+1, aspect='equal')
    plt.imshow(myarray[graph],extent = extent)
       
    plt.xlabel('X',fontsize=5)
    plt.ylabel('Y',fontsize=5)
    plt.colorbar(shrink=1.0)
    
    for name in types:
        plt.title('Graph {}: {}'.format(graph+1, name),fontsize = 10)
```

Any help to make this simpler is very appreciated, thanks in advance! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the subplot axes to index directly.

Here is a toy example indexing the axes, titles, and linestyles:

```py
types = ['Dots', 'Lines']
markers = ['dotted', '-']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)

# then we plot using the above `axes`
for graph in range(2):
    axes[graph].plot([1, 2], [1, 2], ls=markers[graph])
    axes[graph].set_title(f'Graph {graph}: {types[graph]}')
```

[image: axes]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much n_n